# How can I comment a line in a .clang-tidy config file?

Tags: c++, syntax, clang, config, clang-tidy

Please help me to understand how can I comment out a single line from a clang-tidy configuration file.

Answer (score 8):

`#` is acceptable

For example:

`#-bugprone-macro-parentheses,`

Comment: I think `#` is only valid at the start of the the line

Comment: see https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/64343